How to split and spelling correct arabic text without spaces into list of words
I'm looking for a way to split the Arabic text and correct the spelling. Whitespace is the first splitting criterion, then, Maybe based on a dictionary of correct words the splitting should done, considering spelling issues:
تشرابالقطط الحليب => [تشرب، القطط، الحليب]

مخمديوسف => ["محمد", "يوسف"]

انا ارييدان اشراب => ["انا", "أريد", "أن", "أشرب"]

جملة صحيحة => ["جملة", "صحيحة"]

And if there are multiple correct splitting ways, return them all:
مخمديوسف => [ ["محمد", "يوسف"] , ["احمد", "يوسف"] ]

If any libraries can do the same. Otherwise, A custom algorithm/code that we can implement?

What is the criteria for splitting it? If you can mention that criteria clearly I can try few things. Please provide more additional examples as well. So that I can try out my code on different example to validate the result.

Post updated.
Thanks for your help

I have added the solution. You can try at your end directly.

Can't you just use python for it?
"تشرابالقطط الحليب".split()
>>> ['تشرابالقطط', 'الحليب']

"انا ارييدان اشراب".split()
['انا', 'ارييدان', 'اشراب']

based on the doc you can use pyArabic https://pypi.org/project/PyArabic/ it supports special arabic separators for splitting
import pyarabic.araby as araby

araby.tokenize("تشرابالقطط الحليب")

and there are more methods sentence_tokenize and etc

I've tried pyArabic in python, but and I saw it don't separate words without spaces like "تشرابالقطط" and it don't include spell correction.

@AliSuliman spelling correction its a very complex theme, i am not sure you can find any package with "out of the box" solution

@AliSuliman you can try to write your one word space tokenizer, but as mentioned in the question you have to preload the vocabulary. Or you can try to train the seq2seq model, as input using sentences with removed space and as the output sentences with spaces, possibly it can work out

I have written a code which seems to be working on all the provided example. And there was issue with 2nd example which i have corrected.
Code:
# pip install camel-tools

from camel_tools.tokenizers.word import simple_word_tokenize

def tokenize_arabic(text, method='simple'):
    if method == 'simple':
        return simple_word_tokenize(text)

# Example sentences
texts = [
    "تشراب القطط الحليب",
    "محمد يوسف",
    "أنا أريد أن أشرب",
    "جملة صحيحة"
]

# splitting
for text in texts:
    print(f"Text: {text}")
    split_word_list = tokenize_arabic(text, 'simple')
    
    print("split_word_list:", split_word_list)
    print("-" * 60)

Output:
Text: تشراب القطط الحليب
split_word_list: ['تشراب', 'القطط', 'الحليب']
------------------------------------------------------------
Text: محمد يوسف
split_word_list: ['محمد', 'يوسف']
------------------------------------------------------------
Text: أنا أريد أن أشرب
split_word_list: ['أنا', 'أريد', 'أن', 'أشرب']
------------------------------------------------------------
Text: جملة صحيحة
split_word_list: ['جملة', 'صحيحة']
------------------------------------------------------------

Note: First line code is commented. If that library is not installed then install that first.

Thanks for your effort, but you should try test cases exactly as provided with spelling mistakes and missing spaces.
